# Can one reconfigure packages after \usepackage?

Tags: package-options

Is it possible to change the options a package was invoked with after the fact? That is, could one define `\OopsIWishIHadWrittenDraftWhenIncludingGraphicx` so that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\OopsIWishIHadWrittenDraftWhenIncludingGraphicx
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

would produce the same result as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

?

Comment: Have you tried using `\usepackage` a second time with different parameters?

Comment: Depends on the option. In your example you only need to use `\makeatletter\Gin@drafttrue\makeatother`. But not every option is so simple.

Comment: In general, the answer is "no". The problem is that an entirely different branch of the package code may execute, depending on which options are passed to `\usepackage[...]{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it cannot. However, with some packages, providing a package option is equivalent to calling a command in the preamble *after* the package has been loaded. These include for example:

- `hyperref`
- `geometry`
- `enumitem`
- ...